# Correct my view of energy levels in universe?

Tags: solid-state-physics, astrophysics

Kindly apologize me if I am sounding very naive and wrong.
I am very new to the field of solid state physics. I am having this question in my mind.
We know that a solid has energy levels for electrons to occupy which are the result of solid being finite in size and volume. So from this theory we can assume that everything that is finite has specific energy levels for particles to occupy.

What if we apply this theory to the theory of finite universe and then see if we get these specific energy levels in the universes as well? As we have the theory of expanding universe but it can be finite and expanding. So can we correlate the energy of electrons in the universe and see if they occupy certain levels or there energy is continuous in space?

Please tell me if I am way too wrong and apologies for bad formulation.

Answer (score 0):

From my interpretation of your question I believe your idea of finite to be incorrect. You cant really apply the same concepts to a universal scale as the universe itself is made up of matter. That matter is made up of atoms, containing electrons that have an infinite number of energy levels associated with it, albeit over a finite energy range. The idea of combining all these energy levels into one universal energy level and saying our universe is at "blank" energy level cant be applied because it would always be constant due to conservation of energy. Electrons within the universe could be constantly changing levels but as a whole the universe stays constant. Hope this helps!

Comment: I certainly understand your point that I cannot apply the same concepts on a universal scale. But to my surprise people have found confinement of neutrinos under earths gravitational field which although not universal is on a slightly higher scale than crystals. Would be happy to know your opinions on it. Here is the link. https://www.nature.com/articles/415297a